# Greater than in Auto Filter Criteria in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I use greater than in this code?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BG$5158").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:= _ 
">"Range("BJ1").Value, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Here is the complete code

```
Sheets("New Hire").Select 
Range("CI1").Select 
Selection.Copy 

ChDir "D:\Sales Report" 
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Sales Report\Global_New_Hire_Report.xlsb" 
Windows("Global_New_Hire_Report.xlsb").Activate 

Range("BJ1").Select 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ 
:=False, Transpose:=False 

Range("A1").Select 
Selection.AutoFilter 

Windows("Global_New_Hire_Report.xlsb").Activate 
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BG$5158").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:= _ 
">"Range("BJ1").Value, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Answer (score 5):

`Criteria1` argument expects *String* so you need to concatenate it like:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BG$5158").AutoFilter Field:=13, _
    Criteria1:=">" & Range("BJ1").Value
```