# Excel Vba Copy All excel datas to Worksheet with Auto Filter With Button

Tags: excel, vba, copy, autofilter

I am trying to write a vba code that when I click to a button:

1. Creates a new sheet
2. Checks all excel files in a folder(fixed address)
3. Applies an autofilter to column(K13:K) for each cell value equal
   to 10 number after copy them ( OR copy them all after apply filter)
4. Take them all and copy to a new sheet
5. Create a new filter in A1 we have variety product which we want selective list
6. Data which come to new sheet apply to autosize
   row&column,VerticalAlignment,HorizontalAlignment and wrap text

Note : all data must come from a folder which we have all excel files.

Also have a error that

> We can't do that to a merged cell.

```
Sub CopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

    '*-*-*-*

    '*-*-
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\Update\filename.xlsm")

    Sheets("PFMEA").Range("A12:AD3377").Copy
    'Activate the destination worksheet
        Sheets("PFMEA").Activate
    'Select the target range
    Range("A2").Select
    'Paste in the target destination
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    AutoFilterMode = False

                Range("K1:K3377").AutoFilter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("critical").Range("K1:K3377").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=10

    Worksheets("critical").Range("d10").WrapText = True

    '*-*-*-*Resize_Columns_And_Rows_No_Header

        Dim currentSheet As Worksheet

        Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

        Dim Sheet As Worksheet
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            With Sheet
                With Worksheets("Critical").Range("A:AD").Cells.Rows
                    Worksheets("Critical").Range("A:AD").WrapText = True
                    Worksheets("Critical").Range("A:AD").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    Worksheets("Critical").Range("A:AD").EntireRow.AutoFit
                    Worksheets("Critical").Range("A:AD").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With '.Cells.Rows
                Worksheets("Critical").Range("A:AD").Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                Worksheets("Critical").Range("A:AD").EntireRow.AutoFit
            End With 'sheet
        Next Sheet


    '          *-*- Auto filter for product

              ' Range("A1:AD1").AutoFilter
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("critical").Range("A1:AD1").AutoFilter Field:=1

        currentSheet.Activate

    '*******************************
    'Create a Button For Return Back

    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(30, 1, 60, 20).Select
    Selection.Name = "Return Back"

    Selection.OnAction = "CheckTotals"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("New Button").Select

    Selection.Characters.Text = "Return Back"
    '*************************************

    '**************************************
    Sub returnback()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RISK_PRIORITY").Activate
    End Sub



`
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at a filter? And what isn't working with the above (apart from no filter presumably) ?

Comment: i added thanks for interesting

Comment: Which column(s) are you applying filters to? e.g. single column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667555/greater-than-in-auto-filter-criteria-in-vba 2 column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040906/multiple-filtering-in-excel-vba

Comment: There isn't a field 3 in a 2 column range. And did you intend for values between 9 and 11? You will then need to copy the visible rows (minus header potentially)

Comment: i actually want to filtered when it copy because my rows are 3377 but just check Filter Condition is bigger than 10 in G column (G13:G3377)  after that just bigger 10 copy and paste to sheet2( i want to copy just visible rows)

Comment: You need your range, currently A1:B10, to encompass the field you wish to filter on (Column G), or change the range. Which ever column number G is in your range will be the filter field. Your criteria will just be a single criteria of >10.

Comment: i uploaded current code which operator must i choose

Comment: Read my comments regarding the filter field. If your range is G1:G3364 you only have one column and therefore only have field 1 available for a filter.  http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm  This covers the basics though not the best video I have seen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HX2MrYDwwUU

Comment: thank you so much for interesting i will trying your suggestion and read result to hear

Comment: Hello again i have a problem that my code copy a row irrespectively

Comment: Paste special formats etc

Comment: You have a sub with a sub in the above. Did you make a mistake when pasting? See the bottom where you have End Sub End Sub. That second sub should be after the first, not within.